# Would it be a good idea with training reviews?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

Occasionally when you review, you get a test. These are most of the times pretty easy and the purpose seems to be that you're not going on autopilot.

However, since there seem to be quite a lot of questions here about how to review certain cases, I think it would be good if we had a training area for reviewing.

It could work like this:

You do a review of an already reviewed post. After that, you get to see how it was reviewed by different users. The results should not be used by Stack Overflow to determine if you should be allowed to review or not. It should be a place where you safely can practice reviewing.

An alternative is that you skip the part where you say how you would have reviewed it. It could just be a function that lets you view old reviews.

Comment: you could run a userscript to see how you review against your peers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248338/adding-the-consensus-to-reviews-history but that uses your real review history

Comment: There's a simple rule for (almost) never failing on a review: If you're not **100%** sure, skip - other users who are sure will handle it.

Comment: @rene That seems to work. Thanks.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I'm not focusing on avoiding failing. I'm focusing on contributing.

Comment: @klutt if you won't fail (I don't mean audits, I mean making good reviews), you'll be really contributing.

Comment: I really like the idea. For newer reviewers it can be a good thing to have a training area. It would be even more perfect if this training would contain a number of selected questions that are (for one or the other reason) hard to review. And it should have explanations on why this review action was appropriate.

Comment: @rene You have a bug report. :)

Comment: Give me 6 to 8 weeks ...